# Android Call Recording in Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: android

I am working on the Android Call Recording App. It is working fine in some of the devices (MI 3S, HTC Desire 620,OPOO etc.) but getting problems with Samsung Galaxy S7. Remote Voice is not recording in Samsung Galaxy S7. When I am using the ACR this app is working fine. So, basically I want to know what they are using in ACR app that is missing in my Call Recording App. I tried the App using the different options for `AudioSource`, `OutputFormat` and `AudioEncode` but all in vain.

Please help me to find out this problem.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
try {
    recorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
recorder.start();
```

Comment: can u update error log for understanding problem?

Comment: There is no error with the code..its working fine in some devices  but not in Gallaxy S7 , the problem is remote voice is not recorded in it .. or may be it is recorded but not audible. May be I am missing something to add in my code for incoming voice or something else...

Comment: I also have the same problem with my app that it does not record incoming voice in Samsung S7, S8 and Gionee A1. I used MediaRecorder and Audio Recorder too but did nt work for me. If there is any lead please let me know.